# Is there a way to have Python code completion work when inheriting from a variable array of classes?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I am working on a templatized and extensible python library and I want to do something like this:

```
registered_features = [
    feature1.feature.Support,
    feature2.feature.Support,
    feature3.feature.Support,
]
```

where each of those references a class in a directory structure like this:

```
feature1
--feature.py
```

and inside of feature.py is

```
class Support:
    def someExtendedFunctionality(self):
        ....
```

Then I inherit everything like this:

```
class App(*registered_features):
    def __init__(self):
        ....
```

Everything works at runtime, but the issue I hit is for code completion, I get no suggestions for the "registered_features"

Is there any way I can make this work? I'm guessing code completion is a static analysis and expanding that list is a runtime operation. Is there a different way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the classes in `registered_features` don't change and you are using it as a static object to hold a list of classes. If not and it changes during running time, the static analysis wouldn't be able to help with code completion.

So, assuming it's a static class, you can replace it with this instead:

```py
class RegisteredFeatures(SupportA, SupportB, SupportC):
    pass


class App(RegisteredFeatures):
    pass
```

Instead of using a list object to hold all the classes, you use a class that is doing just about the same thing. I tested this and the code completion works with Pycharm 2021.2.3

Comment: perfect! Thank you!